# Turn zero values to empty cells in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a "single-liner" dataframe like this:

```
         Value 1   Value 2   Value 3
code
123            0         3       231
```

I want to turn the zero values into empty, so it gets to look like this:

```
         Value 1   Value 2   Value 3
code
123                      3       231
```

How could I do that?

Comment: Something like: `df[df.eq(0)] = np.nan`?

Comment: to briefly elaborate on @pault comment, you are almost certainly better off with `np.nan` than `''` because the column will be dtype=float rather than object and pandas works much better with numeric columns (float/int) than object or mixed columns.  If the column contains strings rather than numbers then `''` would be fine

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) to find the location of all the zero values across the entire DataFrame, and then replace this with something else, maybe `np.nan`.

```
import numpy as np
df[df.eq(0)] = np.nan
```

Though if you have only one row, you can also replace it with an empty string since you (probably) don't have to worry about the `dtype` for the column changing:

```
df[df.eq(0)] = ''
```

Answer (score 2):

The code below reads like so: set the column 'Value 1' equal to nothing where column 'Value 1' is equal to 0.

```
df.loc[df['Value 1'] == 0, 'Value 1'] = ''
```