# Pandas Pivot table prevent filling empty values with 0

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas DF column (Coded Sentiment (NUM)) that has numerical values, but not all column rows contain a value. See bottom half of the DF some rows are blank.

```
                                             ContentID  Coded Sentiment (NUM)
0    48a799ca7254c59f56daa3aa429f0e250ba294656ab1a6...                    0
1    13674042c5f8e452abaddeec1d1509525f4a3cdfb9f3fb...                    
2    43f821e7431e024ee6b3fe2403847a888f148ffb737f42...                    -1
3    7f9e89d6c2b5b705ff3d1667410f6d21730424e5d79c52...                    0
4    7f9e89d6c2b5b705ff3d1667410f6d21730424e5d79c52...                    1
..                                                 ...                    ...
313  58e18ae5a381450c6f24c5f72c2c71f49e795723d1310f...                    1
314  19fd002ffbaab001a0aa2e8c2373aa5a932b6a40510830...                    
320  b3846c295d5cfe430a8c3faf4078ae7bccb50f1ec7e35e...                    
321  b3846c295d5cfe430a8c3faf4078ae7bccb50f1ec7e35e...                    
322  475bae274bcad23ce3947e4c910b20cfae4aad9aea24a8...                    1
```

I need to create a pivot table to sum the numbers for each unique content ID

```
program_data_sheet_sentiment_fix = program_data_sheet.pivot_table(index='ContentID', values='Coded Sentiment (NUM)', aggfunc= np.sum)
```

Here is where my problem arises, when I create the pivot table, any rows that don't have any number in the sentiment column returns a 0 in the pivot table for that specific content ID.

What I need is for the pivot table to not add the 0 to any blank values. I need to keep the value blank if there are no numerical values associated to that content ID. This is because blank values and the value 0 both mean something different in my data process so it's important to not add 0 for blank values.

So ideally when I create the pivot table, the content ID found at row index 320 & 321 the sum would simply return a blank value since there is nothing in the sentiment column.

Hope this makes sense.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What is the output of `print(df['Coded Sentiment (NUM)'].dtype)`? If you have blank values, your column dtype is string (object) so the function will not add numbers but concatenate them like a string.

Comment: float64 is the dtype of the column

Comment: Did you try `fill_value=''` as argument of `pivot_table`?

Comment: yes I tried program_data_sheet.pivot_table(index='ContentID', values='Coded Sentiment (NUM)', aggfunc= np.sum, dropna=False, fill_value=' ' ) I also tried using a groupby() instead of using a pivot table

Comment: `df.groupby('ContentID')['Coded Sentiment (NUM)'].sum()` doesn't work?

Comment: It returns the same output where blank values are filled with a 0 same as the pivot table

Comment: If you have a float dtype column, I don't understand how you can have blank cells.

Comment: does this answer help ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/48956650/288387